# Ascii Encoder.getString() returning 1500 length

Tags: c#, string, decode, encode

I have a basic encrypted chat. I'm trying to perform a `foreach (char c in encryptedMessage)` but the length is always 1500. How can the empty chars be eliminated? I already try `trim()`.

> This code send:

```
 byte[] msg = new byte[1500];
 [....]
 System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
 msg = enc.GetBytes(encryptedString);
 sck.Send(msg);
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
 sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
```

> This code receive:

```
 byte[] recievedData = new byte[1500];
 recievedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
 //Converting byte[] to string
 ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
 string encrytedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(recievedData);
 foreach(char c in encryptedMessage)
 {
    [....]
 }
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];

 sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
```

Comment: The culprit here is probably the "send" and "receive" part, but you don't outline how that part of the code works. If you decode 1500 bytes into characters, you'll get 1500 characters, there should be no surprise here. The question is, did you *receive* 1500 bytes?

Comment: Yeah its the send and recieve part i am going to update the code so you can see.

Comment: Note that my above comment about 1500 bytes will produce 1500 characters is related to the fact that you use ASCII encoding. Any future visitors here should note that other encoders will not come with that guarantee.

Comment: Sincerely I am new to making projects of chats so I did not know. How can this be fix?

Comment: When you call `EndReceiveFrom` in your async callback method, you get back an `int`, this is the number of bytes actually received.

Comment: You need to implement a framing protocol. When sending strings, usually a prefix indicating the [string's length is enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203930/c-sharp-streaming-sockets-how-to-separate-messages).

Comment: This comment may not be relevant to your situation, but in general it is best to _not_ use ASCII as your transmission character set. C# and .Net (and Java) are based on Unicode, and the world is getting smaller and smaller, so limiting yourself to ASCII characters can become a problem when people using non-English languages try to use your program. Or even people using English but with accented letters in their names or trying to correctly spell city names in other parts of the world. The recommended character set for transmitting characters is now (and has been for many years) UTF-8.